# Randomly forward mobile phone browser to predefined pages

Tags: javascript, html

I have a script that always forwards visitor to "**mob1.html**" page if he uses mobile phone to enter "**index.html**" page on the site. My question is how to edit this script so that visitor can be **randomly forwarded** to one of these pages:

mob1.html

mob2.html

mob3.html

mob4.html

Thank you!

---

script:

```
<script>
if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent))
window.location.replace("http://www.bla.net/mob1.html");
</script>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Answer (score 1):

You can use math.random to generate random number and then redirect to page as per random generated number...

```
<script>
 if(/Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)){
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 4) + 1);
 if(x=='1'){
         window.location.replace("http://www.bla.net/mob1.html");
  }
 if(x=='2'){
         window.location.replace("http://www.bla.net/mob2.html");
 }
 if(x=='3'){
         window.location.replace("http://www.bla.net/mob3.html");
 }
 if(x=='4'){
         window.location.replace("http://www.bla.net/mob4.html");
 }
 }
</script>
```